# mysql requests returning null with php 7.1 while ok with 5.3

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm facing a weird trouble.

I just installed a new virtual server with apache / php 7.1 in order to prepare the migration of my old virtual webserver running php 5.3.3. The reason is I need to install prestashop that requires php 5.4 (minimum requirement).

Both virtual servers are running centos 6 on the same HN.

PHP 7.1 comes from remi repos.

I ran this code on both VMs (CLI):

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli($mysql_adress, $mysql_login, $mysql_pwd, $mysql_database);
if($mysql->connect_error){
    echo 'connect error : '.$mysql->connect_error;
} else {
    $return = $mysql->query("SELECT DATABASE()");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($return, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

My 'old' server returns the name of the database i am connected to (it is the expected result) but the new server returns NULL !

I suspect the mysqlnd client to be responsible for this behaviour but not sure.

Any idea appreciated !

Comment: Is that query right?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's a valid query that should return the database you're currently using. [reference link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_database)

Comment: Yeah, just found that out @AaronW., thanks!

Comment: The php documentation for `mysqli_fetch_array` describes a possible result type as `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, note the I that is not present in your code.

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing procedural and oop? I believe it's allowed but what happens when you try `$row = $return->fetch_assoc();` instead?

Comment: THANK YOU @yanman1234 !!I didn't see the missing 'I'. It used to work without it before but not any more in php 7.1. Problem solved.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead post an answer and mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ! Thank to @yanman1234.

MYSQL_ASSOC used to work with a mysqli object in the previous versions of php .
This time is over and i should now use MYSQLI_ASSOC instead.